# Why do we say "the Indians were put on reservations" and not "in reservations"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, in-on, toponyms

The preposition "on" is used to refer to a surface like "on the floor" or "on the ceiling"
"in" is used to refer as a enclosed space like "in a country" or "in a city".

Why do we say "the Indians were put on reservations" and not "in reservations"?

Comment: Being on the reservation is like being on county land, or public land, or whatnot.

Comment: And, *put* is too mild of a term. Forced onto is a better way of stating this.

Comment: 'The preposition "on" is used to refer to a surface like "on the floor" or "on the ceiling"; "in" is used to refer to an enclosed space like "in a country" or "in a city" ' is a vast over-simplification. Prepositions have been said to have locative/directional usages (on the table; to the station), mildly metaphorical ones (on the train; travelled over the whole country), and highly metaphorical ones (on fire; in the pink). But even this is over-simplistic.

Answer (score 4):

As tchrist stated, [reservations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_reservation) were/are *land*: 2.3% of the area of the United States.

We live *on* land, *on* a mountain or hillside (unless we're Dwarves or Hobbits), and that holds true in most cases. However, we also live *in the mountains* and *hills*, where *in* probably is best interpreted as *among*.

Another roundup and relocation of Americans took place in the case of the Japanese internment camps in 1942. They were forced to live *in* camps — barracks built for them, *in* specific 'zones'. Though a zone is an area, it's like living in a county or township; we live *in* areas, but *on* land.

Comment: Yes, but we live **in** a particular county, city, or state (at least in the US). And we live **on** a particular island. While Indians lived on the lands that made up the reservations, these had firm boundaries like counties cities, islands, etc. I think it is simply idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You live in a country. But you live on a specific piece of land. In this case the specific locatable piece of land is the reservation.

It's like with chess. You put a piece on(to) a square not in(to) a square.

In means in the boundaries (of a country) on means on the specific area enclosed by a boundary.

So you still can say the number of people in the ...-reservation has grown. Then you refer to the inhabitants inside the border.

Also you could say. Instead of forcing indians **on** reservation(s) **land(s)** you could say they were forced to stay **inside** the **borders** of the reservation(s).

Comment: Seems like you'd want “forcing [. . .] onto” in that case.